# How can I close the navbar clicking on the body?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

My navbar looks like this:

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
        <span class="d-flex mx-3">
          <img src="{{ asset('images/logo-small.png') }}" width="30" height="30" alt="Deliveboo">
          <h4 class="mx-3">Deliveboo</h4>
        </span>
        <hr class="mx-3">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center p-3">
          @if (Auth::guest())
            <a class="btn btn-primary text-center" href="{{ route('login') }}"
              role="button">Accedi</a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary text-center" href="{{ route('register') }}"
              role="button">Registrati</a>
          @endif
          @if (Auth::check())
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('restaurants.dashboard') }}" role="button">Vai
              alla tua dashboard</a>
          @endif
        </div>
        <hr class="mx-3">
      </div>
```

These are my scripts:

```
<script>
  function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "375px";
    document.getElementById("root").style.overflow = "hidden";
  }

  function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("root").style.overflow = "auto";
  }
</script>
```

I want the navbar to close when I click outside of it. I'm new to JavaScript.

The entire view:

```
<body id="root">
{{-- HEADER --}}
<header>
  <div id="nav-bg">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light d-flex justify-content-space-between container">
      {{-- LOGO --}}
      <div>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <span class="text-white">
            <img src="{{ asset('images/logo-text.png') }}" width="100" height="40"
            class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="Logo">
          </span>
        </a>
      </div>
      {{-- Navbar buttons --}}
      <div>
        @if (Auth::guest())
          <a class="btn btn-light mx-3" href="{{ route('login') }}" role="button"><i class="fas fa-home mr-2"></i>Accedi o registrati</a>
        @endif
        @if (Auth::check())
          <a class="btn btn-light" href="{{ route('restaurants.dashboard') }}" role="button">Vai alla
            tua dashboard<i class="fas fa-home"></i></a>
        @endif
          <a class="btn btn-light" href="#" role="button" onclick="openNav()"><i class="fas fa-bars mr-2"></i>Menu</a>
      </div>
      {{-- Sidebar --}}
      <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
        <span class="d-flex mx-3">
          <img src="{{ asset('images/logo-small.png') }}" width="30" height="30" alt="Deliveboo">
          <h4 class="mx-3">Deliveboo</h4>
        </span>
        <hr class="mx-3">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center p-3">
          @if (Auth::guest())
            <a class="btn btn-primary text-center" href="{{ route('login') }}"
              role="button">Accedi</a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary text-center" href="{{ route('register') }}"
              role="button">Registrati</a>
          @endif
          @if (Auth::check())
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('restaurants.dashboard') }}" role="button">Vai
              alla tua dashboard</a>
          @endif
        </div>
        <hr class="mx-3">
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  {{-- HERO  --}}
    <div id="hero">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div id="hero-text" class="col-6 mb-5 img-animation">
            <h1>I piatti che ami, a domicilio.</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</header>

{{-- MAIN --}}
<main>
  {{-- DELIVEBOO SECTION  --}}
  <section id="deliveboo-section" class="my-5">
    <div class="container">
      {{-- Section title --}}
      <h2 class="mb-3 font-weight-bold">La selezione di Deliveboo</h2>
      <div class="row">
        {{-- Card Comfort Food --}}
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 d-flex py-3">
          <div class="card flex-grow-1 shadow-sm" style="width: 18rem;">
            <a class="text-decoration-none text-dark" href="{{ route('restaurants.index') }}">
              {{-- Card image --}}
              <img src="{{ asset('images/comfortFood.png')}}" class="card-img-top" alt="Comfort-food">
              <div class="mt-4 p-3">
                {{-- Card title --}}
                <h5 class="card-title">Comfort food</h5>
                {{-- Description --}}
                <p class="card-text">I grandi classici che scaldano il cuore, perfetti in ogni momento.</p>
                <p>Scopri Comfort Food</p>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        {{-- Card Dessert --}}
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 d-flex py-3">
          <div class="card flex-grow-1 shadow-sm" style="width: 18rem;" >
            <a class="text-decoration-none text-dark" href="{{ route('restaurants.index') }}">
              {{-- Card image --}}
              <img src="{{ asset('images/dessert.png')}}" class="card-img-top" alt="dessert">
              <div class="mt-4 p-3">
                {{-- Card title --}}
                <h5 class="card-title">Dolci e dessert</h5>
                {{-- Description --}}
                <p class="card-text">Dolci piaceri per rendere la giornata ancora più gustosa.</p>
                <p>Scopri Dolci e dessert</p>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        {{-- Card Food To Share  --}}
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 d-flex py-3">
          <div class="card flex-grow-1 shadow-sm" style="width: 18rem;">
            <a class="text-decoration-none text-dark" href="{{ route('restaurants.index') }}">
              {{-- Card image --}}
              <img src="{{asset('images/toshare.png')}}" class="card-img-top" alt="food">
              <div class="mt-4 p-3">
                {{-- Card title --}}
                <h5 class="card-title">Perfetti da condividere</h5>
                {{-- Description --}}
                <p class="card-text">Serve una scusa per stare insieme? Ordina dai ristoranti che trasformeranno la tua serata in un vera festa.</p>
                <p>Scopri Perfetti da condividere</p>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        {{-- Card Exclusive Deliveboo  --}}
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 d-flex py-3">
          <div class="card flex-grow-1 shadow-sm" style="width: 18rem;" >
            <a class="text-decoration-none text-dark" href="{{ route('restaurants.index') }}">
              {{-- Card image --}}
              <img src="{{ asset('images/exclusive.png')}}" class="card-img-top" alt="food" >
              <div class="mt-4 p-3">
                {{-- Card title --}}
                <h5 class="card-title">Esclusiva deliveboo</h5>
                {{-- Description --}}
                <p class="card-text">I più famosi, i più buoni, i preferiti. Quelli che trovi solo su Deliveboo.</p>
                <p>Scopri Esclusiva Deliveboo</p>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  {{-- DEFAULT SECTION  --}}
  <section id="default-section" class="py-5">
    <div class="container">
      {{-- Section title --}}
      <h2 class="mb-4 font-weight-bold">I tuoi piatti preferiti, consegnati da noi</h2>
      <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 justify-content-center">
        {{-- FOOD CARD  --}}
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
          <div>
            <a href="{{ route('restaurants.index') }}">
              {{-- Card image --}}
              <img src="{{ asset('images/sushi.jpg')}}" class="card-img-top shadow-sm" alt="Sushi" >
                <div class="mt-2">
                  {{-- Card title --}}
                  <h5 class="card-title text-capitalize">Sushi</h5>
                </div>    
            </a>  
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
          <div>
            <a href="{{ route('restaurants.index') }}">
              {{-- Card Image  --}}
              <img src="{{ asset('images/pokè.jpg')}}" class="card-img-top shadow-sm" alt="Pokè-bowl">
              <div class="mt-2">
                {{-- Card title --}}
                <h5 class="card-title text-capitalize">Pokè bowl</h5>
              </div>
            </a>  
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
          <div>
            <a href="{{ route('restaurants.index') }}">
              {{-- Card Image  --}}
              <img src="{{ asset('images/tacos.jpg')}}" class="card-img-top shadow-sm" alt="Cucina-Messico">
              <div class="mt-2">
                {{-- Card title --}}
                <h5 class="card-title text-capitalize">Cucina messicana</h5>
              </div>
            </a>  
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
          <div>
            <a href="{{ route('restaurants.index') }}">
              {{-- Card image --}}
              <img src="{{ asset('images/fastfood.jpg')}}" class="card-img-top shadow-sm" alt="Fast-food">
              <div class="mt-2">
                {{-- Card title --}}
                <h5 class="mt-2">Fast Food</h5>
              </div>
            </a>  
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
          <div>
            <a href="{{ route('restaurants.index') }}">
              {{-- Card image  --}}
              <img src="{{ asset('images/pizza.jpg')}}" class="card-img-top shadow-sm" alt="Pizza">
              <div class="mt-2">
                {{-- Card title --}}
                <h5 class="card-title text-capitalize">Pizza</h5>
              </div>
            </a>  
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
          <div>
            <a href="{{ route('restaurants.index') }}">
              {{-- Card Image  --}}
              <img src="{{ asset('images/pasta.jpg')}}" class="card-img-top shadow-sm" alt="Pasta">
              <div class="mt-2">
                {{-- Card title --}}
                <h5 class="card-title text-capitalize">Cucina italiana</h5>
              </div>
            </a>  
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
          <div>
            <a href="{{ route('restaurants.index') }}">
              {{-- Card Image  --}}
              <img src="{{ asset('images/pesce.jpg')}}" class="card-img-top shadow-sm" alt="Frittura-di-pesce">
              <div class="mt-2">
                {{-- Card title --}}
                <h5 class="card-title text-capitalize">Pesce</h5>
              </div>
            </a>  
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
          <div>
            <a href="{{ route('restaurants.index') }}">
              {{-- Card Image  --}} 
              <img src="{{ asset('images/kebab.jpg')}}" class="card-img-top shadow-sm" alt="Kebab">
              <div class="mt-2">
                {{-- Card title --}}
                <h5 class="card-title text-capitalize">Kebab</h5>
              </div>
            </a>  
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
          <div>
            <a href="{{ route('restaurants.index') }}">
              {{-- Card Image  --}}
              <img src="{{ asset('images/vietnamita.jpg')}}" class="card-img-top shadow-sm" alt="Cucina-Vietnam">
              <div class="mt-2">
                {{-- Card title --}}
                <h5 class="card-title text-capitalize">Cucina vietnamita</h5>
              </div>
            </a>  
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  {{-- SECTION SUGGESTED  --}}
  <section id="suggested" class="m-5">
    <div class="container">
      <h2 class="mb-4">Cerchi qualcos'altro?</h2>
        @foreach ($types as $type)
          <a href="{{ route('restaurants.index') }}" class="btn px-3">{{ $type->name }}</a>
        @endforeach
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach a listener to body and call `closeNav` if sideBar nav is open Also attach click listener to stop propagation when clicked inside nav bar.

```js
    <script>
       // variable of references to the dom node to avoid querying DOM again and again
       const sideNavBarElem = document.getElementById("mySidenav");
       const rootElem = document.getElementById("root");
       const bodyElem = document.querySelector('body');

       function openNav() {
          sideNavBarElem.style.width = "375px";
          rootElem.style.overflow = "hidden";
          // delay attaching body listener to avoid calling body listener when nav has just opened
          setTimeout(function() {
             bodyElem.addEventListener('click', bodyNavListener);
          }, 0);
       }

       function closeNav() {
          sideNavBarElem.style.width = "0";
          rootElem.style.overflow = "auto";
          bodyElem.removeEventListener('click', bodyNavListener);
       }
       
       function bodyNavListener(){
          // call closeNav fn if navbar is open
          if(sideNavBarElem.style.width !== "0"){
             closeNav();
          }
       }
       
       sideNavBarElem.addEventListener('click', function(event){
             // stop event propagation to avoid closing nav bar due to body click listener
          event.stopPropagation();
       })
    
    </script>
```

[Sample Codepen](https://codepen.io/aqumus/pen/Jjyzrpa)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an event listener to the body and run the function.

```js
const body = document.querySelector('body');
const buttonToOpen = document.querySelector('#buttonSideNav')

function closeNavBody(e) {
  if (e.target.id !== 'mySidenav' || e.target.id !== '#buttonSideNav') {
    closeNav();
    body.removeEventListener('click', myClick);
  }
}

function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "375px";
  document.getElementById("root").style.overflow = "hidden";
  body.addEventListener('click', closeNavBody)
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("root").style.overflow = "auto";
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer! but it does not open anymore T.T

Comment: give me the class of the button to open the sidenav

Comment: <a class="btn btn-light" href="#" role="button" onclick="openNav()"><i class="fas fa-bars mr-2"></i>Menu</a>   you mean this?

Comment: check my answer and add '#buttonSideNav' this id to the button

Comment: check my latest edit

Comment: tried, it remains closed...

Answer (score 0):

You can add an eventListener on the area that is not that element with event.target.
But only do that when nav is open and remove the listener when is closed by removeEventListener() or it would be a load.

Answer (score 0):

Get references to the elements we're working with

```
    const mySideNav = document.getElementById("mySidenav");
    const root =  document.getElementById("root");
    const body = document.getelementByTagName("body");
```

Define our functions

```
    function closeNav() {
         mySidenav.style.width = "0";
         root.style.overflow = "auto";
         body.onclick = undefined;
    }

    function openNav() {
     mySideNav.style.width = "375px";
      root.style.overflow = "hidden";
      body.onclick = closeNav;
    }
```

Comment: nothing...it remains open...i dont even have console errors.